# Texture inside of texture?

Tags: texturing

is there anyway to texture over another texture? for example: lets say i add a musgrave texture to a sphere and use a color ramp to separate the blacks and whites. kinda like this:[image: musgrave applied to sphere]

is there anyway to have a noise texture in the black parts and a wave texture in the white parts? i guess what i mean is: is there anyway to use a texture as bounds for another texture?

forgive my overuse of ":" please. my comma key broke lol. 
thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  The output of the color ramp can be interpreted as a factor, which can be used as input to a color Mix node to mix two textures, like so:

[image]

Comment: i feel stupid now. i cant believe i didnt think of that. thank you for the help!!